# Disable Google groups mail delivery

Tags: google-groups

I subscribed to a high-volume mailinglist hosted on googlegroups.com and I want to (temporarily) disable mail delivery.

How do I do that?

Use-Case: I subscribed because I want to post to this list - but only occasionally. That way I get replies via CC or I can check for replies via the Web interface.

Btw, the mailman software implements this feature: delivery can be configured via sending a command like `set delivery off` to the `*-request` mailing list address.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options that may work depending on your situation:

- There is a choice in the groups interface at groups.google.com that allows you choose how often you receive email from a group. You can just set it to never.
- Set a filter or your mail providers equivalent so that emails from the group are automatically marked as read or deleted
- According to international spam laws all mass email lists require an unsubscribe link at the bottom of the email. Click it if you never wish to leave this mailing list.

  - However if you wish to remain a member of this mailing list but temporarily don't wish to receive mails change the message settings setting to don't send email updates' option. Go to groups.google.com > click on my groups > on the first drop down next to the group you don't want emails from choose 'don't send email updates